# How to determine limits of integration for trig substitution?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I am confused on how to change the limits of integration on this problem after making a trigonometric substitution

$$\int_1^2 \frac{\sqrt {x^2-1}}{x}\,dx $$

I am using $x=\sec \theta$ as my substitution to remove the radical but cannot see how I am supposed to change the limits to $\theta$ since the $\operatorname{arcsec}(2)$ does not exist.

Comment: $\sec^{-1} 2 = \cos^{-1} \frac12$

Comment: The secant of $\theta$ is $2$ wherever the cosine of $\theta$ is $1/2$. This is familiar.

Comment: $x = 1$ correspond to $t  = \pi/2$ and $x = 2$ to $t = \pi/3$

Comment: $\sec^{-1} x$ exists for every real number $x$ such that $|x| \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\operatorname{arcsec} 1 = 0 \text{ and } \operatorname{arcsec} 2 = \frac \pi 3.
$$
The second of these follows from the fact that
$$
\cos\frac \pi 3 = \frac 1 2, \text{ so } \sec\frac\pi 3 = 2.
$$

Take a look at the graph of the secant function on [this page](http://www.nabla.hr/CL-GraphTransFun4.htm) and you will see that $2$ is indeed one of its values.

Comment: I figured it was something simple I was overlooking, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> $$\int\left(\frac{\sqrt {x^2-1}}{x}\right)dx$$

Set $x=\sec(t)$ and $dx=\tan(t)\sec(t)dt$ therefore $\sqrt{x^2-1}=\sqrt{\sec^2(t)-1}=\tan(t)$ and $t=\sec^{-1} x$

$$\int \tan^2(t)dt\overset{\tan^2(t)=\sec^2(t)-1}{=}\int \sec^2 t dt -\int 1 dt=\tan t -t+\mathcal C\\
=\sqrt{x^2-1}-\sec^{-1} x+\mathcal C$$

$$\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}-\sec^{-1} x\right)\bigg|_1^2=\sqrt 3-\frac{\pi}{3}$$